# automatically update model field each time

Tags: django, django-models

in my model named XBlockState i have multiple fields, among them there are **scenario** and **scenarioID** defined like this

```
scenario = models.CharField(
    max_length=255,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    db_index=True,
)
scenarioID = models.CharField(
    max_length=255,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    db_index=True,

)
```

i need to set a value to scenarioID in the following format

> scenario.0

Comment: Could you elaborate further on the `scenario.O` format?

Comment: ok sorry if its unclear, **i.e**  if `scenario = "FirstScenario"` then `scenarioID = "FirstScenario.0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably not the cleanest but it should do the trick:

You could add a scenarioID field

```
scenarioID = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
```

And overwrite the save method to force it's update each time you save an element. Then you can access it and use it for filtering, and in a serialized object.

```
## in models.py ##

class XBlockState(models.Model):
## other fields
...
#scenarioField

scenario = models.CharField(
    max_length=255,
    blank=True,
    null=True,
    db_index=True,
)

def scenarioID_calc_field(self):
    return self.scenario+"."+str(self.pk)

def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None):
    self.scenarioID = self.scenarioID_calc_field() #as defined higher
    super(XBlockState, self).save()
```

Comment: yes that what i need, it's working perfectly now , thanks

Comment: maybe for research purposes you could rewrite your question; making it clearer that a calculated field was not what you were looking for - and have a clearer title ! Could help others !

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure i understand correctly :

1/ Either you mean **scenarioID to be a field of its own**, in which case :

views.py

```
new_scenario = XBlockState.objects.create(
    scenario = "Django Unchained",
    scenarioID = "0"
    )
new_scenario.save()
```

2/ Or you want scenarioID to be a **calculated field** from the primary key, in which case you would want to look at something like:

models.py

```
class XBlockState(models.Model):
    ## other fields
    ...
    #scenarioField

    scenario = models.CharField(
        max_length=255,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
        db_index=True,
    )

    def scenarioID(self):
        return self.scenario+"."+str(self.pk)
```

And you can access that field anywhere using something like

```
xblockstate_instance.scenarioID()
```

Comment: the scenarioID is supposed to be the scenario+string. i.e if `scenario = "FirstScenario"` then `scenarioID = "FirstScenario.0"`

Comment: In which case, the calculated field I wrote higher should work. (Option 2/)

Comment: isn't there a solution without having to create a function, because i'm serializing those fields and returning them with django rest framework and when i tried your solution the scenario id field is not returned